# Hosting Site Not Loading Not Sure What is Going On

Tags: php, ip, hosting, web-hosting

I'm trying to access my hosting service's site which is:

```
www.siteground.com
```

It doesn't load, and when I tried to run the site through www.isitdownrightnow.right it showed this message:

```
Host 'oa-prod-webserver-4' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

Then I tried to connect through a proxy, hide me, website:

```
https://hide.me/en/proxy
```

It worked, and I am able to connect through to the website. However, when I tried to access the cpanel, it kept reloading the page. I'm not sure why this happening, and whether this has something to do with my side, or the hosting services's website.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you ask your hosting service providers support. They should know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed at the vendor's support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue relates to the mySQL connection errors. It seems that due to some issue, there were so many failed attempt to connect the mySQL database server from the localhost/server with the hostname 'oa-prod-webserver-4'.

After max_connect_errors failed requests without a successful connection, mysqld assumes that something is wrong and blocks the host from further connections. You will need to flush the max_connect_errors by executing the command 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'.

As an alternate way, you can also increase the max_connect_errors from the my.ini file.

max_connect_errors=10000;

max_connections = 200;

I also suggest you to check the server logs and resolve the actual error which causes the issue.